# Flutter formatting date from Arabic to English in yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to format Arabic date to english with yyyy-MM-dd and getting
The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'.

```
var format = DateFormat.yMd('en');
var dateString = format.format(frmDate);
var formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(dateString);
```

If anyone can help

Comment: `DateFormat.format` takes a `DateTime` object as an argument, not a `String`.  Why can't you use `DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(frmDate)` directly?  Why do you need `format` and `dateString`?  Can you elaborate what it means to "format Arabic date to English" means?  Do you mean that you want to transform a `String` representing a date in Arabic to another `String` in the `yyyy-MM-dd` format?

Comment: i am trying to get date in English and yyyy-MM-dd format. right it is in Arabic. if convert into English the it print 05/07/2022 like this. i can ether change into English or format but i want first in enslish then in yyyy-MM-dd format